# gesture influence each other

Tags: unity

here is my two of touch function, the first is two finger touch the screen and move the camera;
the 2st one is zoom in-out.

the problem is it often influence each other , when i use it.

like is use two finger move its will exclude a little bit zoom in..

how to fix it??

```
    void touchMve()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount == 2)
        {
            Touch Tozero = Input.GetTouch(0);
            Touch Toone = Input.GetTouch(1);
            if (Tozero .phase == TouchPhase.Moved && Toone.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            {
                transform.Translate(-(Tozero.deltaPosition.x + Toone .deltaPosition.x)/ 2000,
                    -(Tozero.deltaPosition.y + Toone .deltaPosition.y)/ 2000, 0);
            }
        }
    }
```

```
    void touchZoom()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount == 2)
        {
            Touch Tozero = Input.GetTouch(0);
            Touch Toone = Input.GetTouch(1);
            Vector2 Tozeroprevious =  Tozero.deltaPosition - Tozero.position;
            Vector2 Tooneprevious = Toone.deltaPosition - Toone.position;

            float oldTouchDistance = Vector2.Distance(Tozeroprevious, Tooneprevious);
            float CurrentTouchdistance = Vector2.Distance(Tozero.position, Toone.position);
            float Offset = oldTouchDistance - CurrentTouchdistance;
            if (Tozero.phase == TouchPhase.Moved && Toone.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            {
                transform.Translate(0, 0, - Offset / 1000);
             }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's more of a human error rather than a programming issue. We can't keep the distance between two fingers perfectly unchanged when moving the camera, right?

Though I have two ideas that may help you:

1. Don't zoom in if the distance change is small. Just write a simple if and check if the distance (in relation to their first position) is less than `X` or not
2. Let them choose. This one's way easier but will limit your user to do only one of them at a time. You can simply make a switch and let them choose what they want to do right now, moving or zooming?